# How to disable event for a particular element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to disable click event for a particular event using jQuery, for example

```
$('.code') // selection of all elements having class div
```

the structure of `".code"` div's are like table
Now during the course of the program when a user click one div, the current div as well as the surrounding div should disable clicking .

if i use `off` here it will disable all the click event of `class = "code"` but i don't want that, i only want to disable few targeted element, can anyone please help me??

I have searched for this answer through the web and haven't found any satisfying answer.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/El1SR.png)

Comment: Your question is unclear can you please elaborate?

Comment: *i only want to disable few targeted element*, what are these elements? You just need to specify the correct selector to select only these elements.

Comment: Of course you will need to add an id for that particular element or an specific class or attribute to those particular elements...

Comment: @brank but id's can't be added to multiple div's

Comment: Then you must create a class for this porpuse or an attribute.

Comment: @brank that works , thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return false for click events. It will not effect other behaviors of the html.

```js
$("#elementToDisableClick").on("click", function(){
    return false;
});

$("#elementToDisableClick").on("mouseover", function(){
    alert("");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="elementToDisableClick" class="code">SomeText</div>
```

Here click event is disabled and mouseover is still working!

**Answer** : assign classes to the div's.

Comment: add id to all the other div as well??

Comment: in that case you will have to add a common class to all those div's you want to make disabled. And change the selector to $(".classname"). Because id is for single element and class is for multiple elements.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable click event for specific element, add an id to this element and use `preventDefault()`:

**HTML**

```
<a id="disableClick" href="" class="code">...</a>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#disableClick').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: does `preventDefault` prevent all other event handlers from running? I thought it only prevented the default html behaviour (like links opening a new page).